# Is $f$ analytic?

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $f(x,y) = \frac{-4x}{4x^2 + 4y^2 + 4y + 1} + i \frac{1 - 4x^2 -4y^2}{4x^2 + 4y^2 + 4y + 1}$, is this function analytic? And, assuming so, how can we write $f$ in terms of a variable $z$?

To check if it's analytic, I would have to check if $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v }{\partial y}$ and if $-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$. However, doing the partials for $f$ would be tedious and take awhile. Is there a shortcut?

Also, how do we actually write $f$ in terms of $z$?

Comment: Well, if $z=x+yi$, then $x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$ and $y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$, so just make the appropriate substitutions.

Comment: I'm a bit new to complex analysis, but no, make y=0 and solving the denominator for 0 gives two poles at $x=\pm i/4$.